# Dynamically removing table from rdlc report

Tags: ssrs-2008, reportviewer, reporting-services, rdlc

I'm creating an SSRS report in VS2012.

Under Tablix Properties I can show or hide a table using an expression which uses a boolean parameter; but this leaves a gap in the report.

Is there a way I can just remove the table?

Answer (score 0):

You could call a subreport and determine different subreports based on a variable.  You cannot remove space with SSRS to my knowledge of it, it is not designed to remove space, just perform different actions on objects that take up space.  I don't even think you can resize the objects dynamically unfortunately.  You can cheat though and make two subreports, one with the supposed table and one without.  Then when your variable gets hit it calls one and not the other.  Since a subreport can change sizes that is a way to thus trick the system's language limitations.  It may not fit your needs but it is a thought that could in theory solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the report layout and all sorts. I created the simplest case:

[image]

From Designer mode you can see it's just three tables in the report, nothing else. The middle table's visibilty is parameter based. In this case, SSRS does make an effort to shift the last table depending on whether the middle is visible:

[image]

[image]

In this case you still have maybe too much whitespace showing. There are various ways around this. One example is embedding the middle table in a Rectangle that extends to top of the last table, then moving the visibility expression from the table to the Rectangle. In Designer:

[image]

End result, looks better:

[image]

I guess all I'm trying to show is that SSRS does sometimes move things around based on visibility, but you can also apply extra control using tools like Rectangles to control visibility and layout.

Comment: @Kryptonite, did this help your issue? If not, can you please provide more information?